# How to get all JNDI db options?

Tags: java, servlets, jndi

i need some help. I have to retrieve whole jndi db options to a selectlist in a html file which means i need to access all jndi db names and get these values 
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble finding JNDI names in one of my WebLogic servers. I created a method that iterates through the JDNI tree structure, and prints all of them to the console. I am not sure that this is what you need, but here is the code I used for it:

```
private void printList(String directory){
        try {
            NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> namings = context.list(directory);
            System.out.println("************Printing " + directory + "**************");
            while(namings.hasMoreElements()){
                if(directory.equals("")) printList(namings.next().getName());
                else printList(directory+"."+namings.next().getName());
            }
        System.out.println("Done printing " + directory);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(directory);
        }
    }
```

you can pass a string of a desired directory, or an empty string, if you want all elements from the root. You'll need to import `javax.naming.*` (or `-NamingEnumeration`/`-NameClassPair`)

**Almost forgot:**
you'll first need to define a context for where the method should look for the directory:

```
Context context = null;
        Hashtable<String, String> ht = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "your_host");
        ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        //this above needs to be changed to fit your desired system
        ht.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "your_user");
        ht.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "your_password");
        try {
            context = new InitialContext(ht);
            // Use the context in your program
        }
        catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: You can't necessarily do this in all containers. It isn't required by the Servlet specification AFAIK.

Comment: I might have been a little premature in my answering here. There really isn't enough info to go on. At least not for me. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @KjetilNordin  ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"your_host"); and other ht.put gives error. Cause Context.PRO... is not exist

Comment: you will have to replace "your_host" with the actual name (URL:port) of your host. That also goes for your user and your password, as well as the initial context factory, as I have no ieda what kind of setup you have there. You haven't told us.